# Environment variables from external file in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a file which contains some environment variables that will be used by Django and I need ansible to access some of those info.

Example `env_vars` file:

```
DB_USER='my_db_username'
DB_PASSWORD='my_db_password'
```

Example `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: localhost

  tasks:
        - debug: msg="username {{ lookup('env', 'DB_USER') }} password {{ lookup('env', 'DB_PASSWORD') }}"
```

When I try calling it with `-e` option it fails with the following error:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @env_vars

ERROR: failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'str'
```

I also tried to "source" the `env_vars` file. But ansible cant see the enviroment variables.

```
$ . env_vars; ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [Test playbook] ********************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug msg="username  password "] *************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "username  password "
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Is there a way to make ansible "see" or "load" those variables set in the file? I've seen many lookup options (ini, yml and others), but none of them load this kind of info.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308581/4335271) is an answer on how to `source` a file in Ansible. I would expect it to work with env vars as well, but only inside a single task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
DB_USER='my_db_username'
DB_PASSWORD='my_db_password'
```

to:

```
export DB_USER='my_db_username'
export DB_PASSWORD='my_db_password'
```

Comment: IDK why but your answer did not work for me, it throw this error `ERROR! Invalid extra vars data supplied. '@env' could not be made into a dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

`--extra-vars "@env_vars.json"` and within the env_vars.json have

```
{
  "db_user": "xxx",
  "db_password": "xxx"
}
```

no need to do a lookup.

Comment: I don't think this answers OPs question.  They are asking for environment variables not just variables which don't behave the same.