# How to source a file from Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have added few env variables in the /etc/profile and I am able to do so succesfuly. Now I want to source /etc/profile from ansible script so that in the current shell the env variables are set. I can do this manually by :

```
source /etc/profile
. /etc/profile
```

I have tried below ways. The script is runnning withput giving any error but the env variables aren't set in the current shell . My intention is to avoid manual steps as much as possible .

```
# - name: Execute the command in remote shell; stdout goes to the specified file on the remote
#   #sudo: no
#   command: . /etc/profile 
  #ansible.builtin.shell: configuration/files/source.sh
# - name: source bashrc
#   ansible.builtin.shell: "source /etc/profile"

- name: Get the value of the environment variable we just added
  #sudo: no 
  shell: '/bin/bash -i -c "source /etc/profile"'
  # become-user: {your_remote_user}
  # args:
  #   executable: /bin/sh

# - name: Add another bin dir to system-wide $PATH.
#   copy:
#     src: env_vars.sh
#     dest: /etc/profile
#     #content: 'HADOOP_HOME=/opt/spark/hadoop-3.1.1'
```

I am using ansible-core 2.12 . Is there a way we can source /etc/profile from ansible itself ?

Comment: `shell: "source /etc/profile && echo $variable_in_profile"` should work. Mind that each and every task Ansible run is run in a separate SSH connection, so, If you expect those variable to live outside of the task where your sourced the file, then you should try another approach, like defining those in the variable of your host in your inventory, for example.

Answer (score 3):

### Using `source` in the `ansible.builtin.shell` module:

As user [@β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%CE%B2-%CE%B5%CE%B7%CE%BF%CE%B9%CF%84-%CE%B2%CE%B5) mentioned - each `ansible.built.shell` task that you want to have access to your environment must have its command parameter start with `source /etc/profile && ...`.

I believe this method can't be used for tasks that are of a type different from `ansible.builtin.shell`.

In my case, I needed to change from `sh` to `/bin/bash` using the `executable` parameter. If you use some shell other than `/bin/bash` on your host (script's target machine), you can find its path with `echo $SHELL`.

So the end result should look something like this:

```
- name: Source a file and run my command foo
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    executable: /bin/bash
    cmd: "source /etc/profile && foo"
```

### Defining environment variables in plays:

Alternatively, you can define individual environment variables for plays, blocks, or tasks using the [`environment` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_environment.html).

Task example:

```
- name: Run the command foo
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "foo"
  environment:
    NVM_DIR: /var/local/nvm
    PATH: /var/local/nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}
```

### Variables only for Ansible tasks

If you need to access some variables only inside Ansible tasks, you can use regular Ansible [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html) instead. There are a lot of options, among those - reading [variables from a .yaml file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-included-files-and-roles).